# Auto switching push environment for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, push, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Ok, heres the deal.
I use elastic beanstalk and have two environments. Each of them have their own name and url, lets say env-one = foo.elasticbeanstalk.com and env-two = bar.elasticbeanstalk.com.

Then we have the production domain: example.com.

example.com have a cname pointing to foo.elasticbeanstalk.com

The default pushing environment is env-two.

I push to the default environment and check that everything works fine, just like a normal dev environment. When everyone is happy, I switch the urls so that the dev environment turns into the production environment and the other way around.

So now, env-two = foo.elasticbeanstalk.com and env-one = bar.elasticbeanstalk.com

The problem is, the default pushing environment is still env-two, but this has now turned into the production environment. So next time i need to push to dev, I have to define that I want to push to env-one.

```
git aws.push --environment env-one
```

So, what I'm looking for is a way to not have to define what environment I want to push to.

Thanks in advance for answers. I hope there is a sollution to this.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1) This is a bit outside of the scope you asked (and I'm not an AWS expert), but given DNS propigation delays if this is a public site, DNS switching might leave you with a collision window.

2) You could define a 2nd DNS alias "dev.elasticbeanstalk.com" and swap it at the same time, then always push to that one.

3) If you're only pushing from one local repo you could do some "git remote set-url" magic to switch URLs around so you're pushing to the right one.  However, this seems to be potentially error prone to me.

If I were going to stay with DNS I'd use option # and then set up a monitoring system which will trigger if "dev." and "example.com" were pointing to the same A record.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a git repo to deploy on AWS EB with [this instruction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.sdlc.html) (I selected PHP one, other languages workflow is the same) and run *eb init* command it creates special *.elasticbeanstalk* folder that contains description for environment.

When you run *eb start* command the environment is created using that description.

Each time when you call *git aws.push* command - new remote git URL is generated. It depends from application name, environment name, commit id, local time and AWS credentials. Only that generated URL is used in *git aws.push* command - git repository remote URLs are ignored. Since URL depends from current time it is always different.

To deploy on another environment by default you can just change *EnvironmentName* option in *.elasticbeanstalk\config* file (if your environments are in the same application and have similar settings).

If your environment is in another application or one settings are different I think you should delete *.elasticbeanstalk* folder and run *eb init* command again passing answers based on your already existing environment parameters. After that you can pass *eb init* command (since environment already exists) and just continue with *git aws.push*.